# How is $\log _{10}(e)=\left[\log _e(10)\right]^{-1}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, eulers-number-e

I am watching a logarithm lecture from 3Blue1Brown  (great for math dummies like me!)
Here is the video for context:
https://youtu.be/4PDoT7jtxmw?t=1306

The step that I did not follow is when he equates the LHS and RHS of the equation below.
Maybe someone can fill me in on the general rule that allows us to claim this equality?
thanks in advance !

$\log _{10}(e)=\left[\log _e(10)\right]^{-1}$

Comment: Let $e^x = 10$, then taking $x$th root gives $10^{1/x} = e$.

Comment: For any legitimate bases (positive and not equal to one)  we always have $\log_a b = \frac 1{\log_b a}$.  Why?  Well.  Let $\log_e (10) = k$.  That means $e^k = 10$.  Raise both to the $\frac 1k$ and we get $(e^k)^{\frac 1k}=10^{\frac 1k}$ or $e = 10^{\frac 1k}$.  And that means.... $\log_{10} e = \frac 1k$.  And as $k = \log_e {10}$ we have $\log_{10}e = \frac 1k = \frac 1{\log_e 10}$.

Comment: in other words  $\log_a b = k;b\ne 1 \iff a^k = b;b\ne 1;k \ne 0 \iff a = b^{\frac 1k} \iff \log_b a =\frac 1k$.  Thus *whatever* $\log_a b$ equals we always have $\log_b a =\frac 1{\log_a b}$.  (Assuming that $\log_a b$ exists at all. ..... and $b\ne 1$

Comment: Got it !  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably based on the base change formula that is well-known:

$
\operatorname{log}_b{a} = \frac{\operatorname{log}{b}}{\operatorname{log}{a}}
$

From this, raising to -1 power means flipping the fraction

$
\operatorname{log}_b{a} = \frac{\operatorname{log}{b}}{\operatorname{log}{a}} = \bigl[\frac{\operatorname{log}{a}}{\operatorname{log}{b}}\bigr]^{-1} = \bigl[\operatorname{log}_a{b}\bigr]^{-1} 
$